# exec command unless directory exists in puppet

Tags: ruby, puppet

How to exec a command if directory does not exists in puppet file?

```
exec { "my_exec_task":
  command => "tar zxf /home/user/tmp/test.tar.gz",
  unless => "test -d /home/user/tmp/new_directory",
  path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/",
}
```

I get error: "Could not evaluate: Could not find command 'test'". Also is this the best practice to check if directory does not exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`test` work for me at `/usr/bin`, so adding it to path could solve error.

```
unless => 'bash -c "test -d /home/user/tmp/new_directory"',
```

Should work too. But I think the correct way is to use `creates`:

```
exec { "my_exec_task":
  command => "tar zxf /home/user/tmp/test.tar.gz",
  creates => "/home/user/tmp/new_directory",
  path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/bin/",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actual  problem is in path:
path => [ '/usr/local/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin' ]